# music/video files not playing after installing libcanberra-gtk*

Tags: 18.04

I recently installed libcanberra-gtk* module for my jupyter notebook, it fixed that problem but later that, i went to the youtube and video contents not playing properly, i tested it with downloading, it wasn't playing, movies, stremio, youtube etc, Audio files are not working either.

- I fixed the issue with restarting my system but it happened again
  after 30 minutes of watch.
- restricted-extras are updated.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with `killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*` and `pulseaudio -k`